# Full-text search on email address column breaks when using wildcards

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, wildcard

I'm trying to perform a full-text search on a table which contains email addresses.

Let's say my table contains the email address: **a.b.builder@realestate.com**

Now, because of word breakers the periods in this email address function as a separator. The default SQL Server Stoplist prevents single characters to be indexed (for obvious reasons).

Normally not an issue and searching for the address works just fine. However, I want to be able to search for *parts* of the address.

I'd like to search for **"a.b.builder@real"** by using the query below. This will not work unfortunately, because the address isn't indexed as "a.b.builder@real...".

> SELECT 
>       * 
>   FROM 
>       [Addressbook] a
>   WHERE 
>       CONTAINS([a].*, ' "a.b.builder@real*" ')

Any suggestions on how to solve this? Test example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/658cf).

Comment: Did you got this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE operator:

```
SELECT * FROM [Addressbook] a WHERE EmailAddress LIKE 'a.b.builder@real%';
```

You can only pass a string value to a second parameter in `CONTAINS`. I don't think there is a way of bypassing this without compromising performance in the first place.

So if you pass a `wildcard` it will take the whole string value as condition:

```
SELECT * FROM [Addressbook] a WHERE CONTAINS([a].*, 'a.b.builder@real*')
```

You can see a link hire for functions that you can use on strings [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like). The only way i can see that you can solve this is by writing some sort of LIKE function yourself then passing the value that is return'd in to a CONTAINS. But that will make your performance even worse than just using a LIKE operator.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/658cf/16)

Comment: I'm using full-text indexing for performance reasons. This is why I would like to see a solution using CONTAINS.